# How to insert glyphicon icon in my website?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[How to insert glyphicon icon  in my website. Now I'm trying to put icon in my website but not fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j39HG.png)

Comment: did you call the fonts to your folder

Comment: how to call glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff etc?

Comment: you dont need to call the fonts to css, you just plase the font files to fonts folder

Comment: already placed in the fonts folder .it doesn't work! when I am online it is work.

Comment: if your css is in folder-1 and font files in folder-2 then folder-1 and folder-2 should be in same directory/folder

Comment: check your console, is there any error?

Comment: There is an error !

Answer (score 0):

Without a part of your code we can't be really helpfull.

However, to me it looks like you forgot to use the property @font-face.

See the doc:
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Answer (score 0):

When using Bootstrap, use a span with the class 'glyphicon' and another class specified for each icon, like so:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

[Here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) you can find all icons Bootstrap is currently offering.